# serial port sending decimal value 1000 but receiving 232 instead using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, serial-port

I am trying to read decimal value from serial port which send me 1000 but my function is receiving only 232. I am able to receive values correctly upto 127. Also It is receiving all string values correctly.

```
private void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bytes = 255;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            bytes = mySerialPort.BytesToRead;
            mySerialPort.Read(buffer, i, bytes);
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        } while (mySerialPort.BytesToRead != 0);
        rxInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayDecimal));
    }
```

Comment: What is the implementation of displayDecimal?

Comment: You need to show the transmitting code that encodes the number, as well as more details of the receiver like how data is decoded/displayed.

Comment: displayDecimal function appends the received data in a textbbox txt_temp,                                                                                                         
 private int rxInt;                                                                       
private void displayDecimal(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_temp.AppendText(rxInt.ToString());
        }

Comment: @AmitSingh See my answer below.  Get your serial transmitter working first with a terminal program, then once that is working, return to the question of the code above.  It is always prudent to only debug one half of an interface at one time.  Get the sender working as you expect, then attend to the code above,

Comment: Edit the code for the transmitter into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's explain that strange result:

The value 1000 is too big to fit in a byte.  The hex value of decimal 1000 is 0x3E8.  Since the serial port can only send a byte at a time, the lower part 0xE8, gets transmitted.  The decimal value of 0xE8 is ... 232.  So the seemingly weird transformation from 1000 to 232 is completely explained.

What to do about it?  Bottom line is that you cannot stuff any value larger than 255 in a C# Byte structure (or -128 to 127 for SByte).  You didn't mention what is sending the data, so I can't advise on that, but you need to break your data up into bytes for serial transmission **or send it as a string** (which you've already commented that works).  There is a lot of help here on SO and on the internet at large in how to do that.

Comment: thanks for the help, tried every possible way to receive unsigned integer greater than 255 but in vain, ultimately I decided to send number as string from the sender side. It is working fine now.

Comment: @AmitSingh   You're welcome! I invite you to show your thanks by clicking on the gray "Accept" icon to accept my answer.  Accepted answers are more likely to be found -- and more likely to help -- other users in the future.